# JS не "видит" динамически подключаемый CSS-файл

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте!

Есть HTML-файл, в head которого, с помощью скрипта, динамически подключается CSS-файл (чтобы "потешить" Google page speed). После этого скрипта подключаются остальные JS-библиотеки и скрипты. Если скрипт пытается получить стиль элемента, то выдаётся стиль браузера.

Пример:
Есть div с классом .test. В подключённом с помощью скрипта CSS-файле указана ширини блока .test (width=200px). Но если запросить ширину из скрипта то будет получена ширина по умолчанию 1920px (ширина окна браузера), как-будто файл со стилем не подключился.

Добавление стиля и подключение скриптов (в конце body)

```
<!-- Load CSS -->
<script>
    function LoadFile(arrLibs){
        var i,
                ext,
                file,
                link;

        for( i = 0; i < arrLibs.length; i++ ){
            file = arrLibs[i];
            link = document.createElement("link");
            link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            link.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            link.setAttribute("href", file);

            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link)
            console.log('1.'+i);
        }
    }

    var arrLibs = [
    'css/style.css'
    ];

    LoadFile(arrLibs);
    console.log('1');
</script>
<!-- Load CSS -->


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<!-- jQuery -->

<!-- JS Libs -->
<script src="js/libs.min.js"></script>
<!-- JS Libs -->

<!-- Custom js -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<!-- Custom js -->
```

Если отложить выполнение скрипта, то всё работает нормально

```
$(function(){
  var interval = setTimeout(function(){
    console.log( $('.test').width() );
  },200);
});
```

Вопрос:
Как добавить CSS на страницу с помощью скрипта так, чтобы обращаться к нему из JS без костылей?

Comment: Скорее всего, вы обращаетесь к стилям тогда, когда файл стилей еще не загрузился. Попробуйте  `$(window).load(function() { console.log( $('.test').width() ); })`

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.